# mautrix-whatsapp bridge setup with matrix-synapse

Tags: help-files

So i just finally got my matrix server up and running but now whenever i try run whatsapp bridge after adding path in "app_service_config_files" i get this error:

```
 [FATAL] The as_token was not accepted. Is the registration file installed in your homeserver correctly?
```

i have -restarted server before doing these steps
-pointed the full path to registration.yml file

the brige config file :

```
# Homeserver details.
homeserver:
    # The address that this appservice can use to connect to the homeserver.
    address: http://localhost:8008
    # The domain of the homeserver (for MXIDs, etc).
    domain: localhost

    # Is the homeserver actually mautrix-asmux?
    asmux: false
    # The URL to push real-time bridge status to.
    # If set, the bridge will make POST requests to this URL whenever a user's whatsapp connection state changes.
    # The bridge will use the appservice as_token to authorize requests.
    status_endpoint: null
    # Endpoint for reporting per-message status.
    message_send_checkpoint_endpoint: null

# Application service host/registration related details.
# Changing these values requires regeneration of the registration.
appservice:
    # The address that the homeserver can use to connect to this appservice.
    address: http://localhost:29318

    # The hostname and port where this appservice should listen.
    hostname: 0.0.0.0
    port: 29318

    # Database config.
    database:
        # The database type. "sqlite3" and "postgres" are supported.
        type: sqlite3
        # The database URI.
        #   SQLite: File name is enough. https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3#connection-string
        #   Postgres: Connection string. For example, postgres://user:password@host/database?sslmode=disable
        #             To connect via Unix socket, use something like postgres:///dbname?host=/var/run/postgresql
        uri: mautrix-whatsapp.db
        # Maximum number of connections. Mostly relevant for Postgres.
        max_open_conns: 20
        max_idle_conns: 2
        # Maximum connection idle time and lifetime before they're closed. Disabled if null.
        # Parsed with https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseDuration
        max_conn_idle_time: null
        max_conn_lifetime: null

    # Settings for provisioning API
    provisioning:
        # Prefix for the provisioning API paths.
        prefix: /_matrix/provision/v1
        # Shared secret for authentication. If set to "generate", a random secret will be generated,
        # or if set to "disable", the provisioning API will be disabled.
        shared_secret: generate

    # The unique ID of this appservice.
    id: whatsapp
    # Appservice bot details.
    bot:
        # Username of the appservice bot.
        username: whatsappbot
        # Display name and avatar for bot. Set to "remove" to remove display name/avatar, leave empty
        # to leave display name/avatar as-is.
        displayname: WhatsApp bridge bot
        avatar: mxc://maunium.net/NeXNQarUbrlYBiPCpprYsRqr

    # Whether or not to receive ephemeral events via appservice transactions.
    # Requires MSC2409 support (i.e. Synapse 1.22+).
    # You should disable bridge -> sync_with_custom_puppets when this is enabled.
    ephemeral_events: false

    # Authentication tokens for AS <-> HS communication. Autogenerated; do not modify.
    as_token: "This value is generated when generating the registration"
    hs_token: "This value is generated when generating the registration"

# Prometheus config.
metrics:
    # Enable prometheus metrics?
    enabled: false
    # IP and port where the metrics listener should be. The path is always /metrics
    listen: 127.0.0.1:8001

# Config for things that are directly sent to WhatsApp.
whatsapp:
    # Device name that's shown in the "WhatsApp Web" section in the mobile app.
    os_name: Mautrix-WhatsApp bridge
    # Browser name that determines the logo shown in the mobile app.
    # Must be "unknown" for a generic icon or a valid browser name if you want a specific icon.
    # List of valid browser names: https://github.com/tulir/whatsmeow/blob/2a72655ef600a7fd7a2e98d53ec6da029759c4b8/binary/proto/def.proto#L1582-L1594
    browser_name: unknown

# Bridge config
bridge:
    # Localpart template of MXIDs for WhatsApp users.
    # {{.}} is replaced with the phone number of the WhatsApp user.
    username_template: whatsapp_{{.}}
    # Displayname template for WhatsApp users.
    # {{.PushName}}     - nickname set by the WhatsApp user
    # {{.BusinessName}} - validated WhatsApp business name
    # {{.Phone}}        - phone number (international format)
    # The following variables are also available, but will cause problems on multi-user instances:
    # {{.FullName}}  - full name from contact list
    # {{.FirstName}} - first name from contact list
    displayname_template: "{{if .PushName}}{{.PushName}}{{else if .BusinessName}}{{.BusinessName}}{{else}}{{.JID}}{{end}} (WA)"
    # Should the bridge create a space for each logged-in user and add bridged rooms to it?
    # Users who logged in before turning this on should run `!wa sync space` to create and fill the space for the first time.
    personal_filtering_spaces: false
    # Should the bridge send a read receipt from the bridge bot when a message has been sent to WhatsApp?
    delivery_receipts: false
    # Should incoming calls send a message to the Matrix room?
    call_start_notices: true
    # Should another user's cryptographic identity changing send a message to Matrix?
    identity_change_notices: false
    # Should a "reactions not yet supported" warning be sent to the Matrix room when a user reacts to a message?
    reaction_notices: true
    portal_message_buffer: 128
    # Settings for handling history sync payloads. These settings only apply right after login,
    # because the phone only sends the history sync data once, and there's no way to re-request it
    # (other than logging out and back in again).
    history_sync:
        # Should the bridge create portals for chats in the history sync payload?
        create_portals: true
        # Maximum age of chats in seconds to create portals for. Set to 0 to create portals for all chats in sync payload.
        max_age: 604800
        # Enable backfilling history sync payloads from WhatsApp using batch sending?
        # This requires a server with MSC2716 support, which is currently an experimental feature in synapse.
        # It can be enabled by setting experimental_features -> msc2716_enabled to true in homeserver.yaml.
        # Note that prior to Synapse 1.49, there were some bugs with the implementation, especially if using event persistence workers.
        # There are also still some issues in Synapse's federation implementation.
        backfill: false
        # Use double puppets for backfilling?
        # In order to use this, the double puppets must be in the appservice's user ID namespace
        # (because the bridge can't use the double puppet access token with batch sending).
        # This only affects double puppets on the local server, double puppets on other servers will never be used.
        double_puppet_backfill: false
        # Should the bridge request a full sync from the phone when logging in?
        # This bumps the size of history syncs from 3 months to 1 year.
        request_full_sync: false
    # Should puppet avatars be fetched from the server even if an avatar is already set?
    user_avatar_sync: true
    # Should Matrix users leaving groups be bridged to WhatsApp?
    bridge_matrix_leave: true
    # Should the bridge sync with double puppeting to receive EDUs that aren't normally sent to appservices.
    sync_with_custom_puppets: true
    # Should the bridge update the m.direct account data event when double puppeting is enabled.
    # Note that updating the m.direct event is not atomic (except with mautrix-asmux)
    # and is therefore prone to race conditions.
    sync_direct_chat_list: false
    # When double puppeting is enabled, users can use `!wa toggle` to change whether
    # presence and read receipts are bridged. These settings set the default values.
    # Existing users won't be affected when these are changed.
    default_bridge_receipts: true
    default_bridge_presence: true
    # Should the bridge always send "active" delivery receipts (two gray ticks on WhatsApp)
    # even if the user isn't marked as online (e.g. when presence bridging isn't enabled)?
    #
    # By default, the bridge acts like WhatsApp web, which only sends active delivery
    # receipts when it's in the foreground.
    force_active_delivery_receipts: false
    # Servers to always allow double puppeting from
    double_puppet_server_map:
        example.com: https://example.com
    # Allow using double puppeting from any server with a valid client .well-known file.
    double_puppet_allow_discovery: false
    # Shared secrets for https://github.com/devture/matrix-synapse-shared-secret-auth
    #
    # If set, double puppeting will be enabled automatically for local users
    # instead of users having to find an access token and run `login-matrix`
    # manually.
    login_shared_secret_map:
        example.com: foobar
    # Should the bridge explicitly set the avatar and room name for private chat portal rooms?
    private_chat_portal_meta: false
    # Should Matrix m.notice-type messages be bridged?
    bridge_notices: true
    # Set this to true to tell the bridge to re-send m.bridge events to all rooms on the next run.
    # This field will automatically be changed back to false after it, except if the config file is not writable.
    resend_bridge_info: false
    # When using double puppeting, should muted chats be muted in Matrix?
    mute_bridging: false
    # When using double puppeting, should archived chats be moved to a specific tag in Matrix?
    # Note that WhatsApp unarchives chats when a message is received, which will also be mirrored to Matrix.
    # This can be set to a tag (e.g. m.lowpriority), or null to disable.
    archive_tag: null
    # Same as above, but for pinned chats. The favorite tag is called m.favourite
    pinned_tag: null
    # Should mute status and tags only be bridged when the portal room is created?
    tag_only_on_create: true
    # Should WhatsApp status messages be bridged into a Matrix room?
    # Disabling this won't affect already created status broadcast rooms.
    enable_status_broadcast: true
    # Should the status broadcast room be muted and moved into low priority by default?
    # This is only applied when creating the room, the user can unmute/untag it later.
    mute_status_broadcast: true
    # Should the bridge use thumbnails from WhatsApp?
    # They're disabled by default due to very low resolution.
    whatsapp_thumbnail: false
    # Allow invite permission for user. User can invite any bots to room with whatsapp
    # users (private chat and groups)
    allow_user_invite: false
    # Whether or not created rooms should have federation enabled.
    # If false, created portal rooms will never be federated.
    federate_rooms: true
    # Whether to enable disappearing messages in groups. If enabled, then the expiration time of
    # the messages will be determined by the first user to read the message, rather than individually.
    # If the bridge only has a single user, this can be turned on safely.
    disappearing_messages_in_groups: false
    # Should the bridge never send alerts to the bridge management room?
    # These are mostly things like the user being logged out.
    disable_bridge_alerts: false
    # Should the bridge detect URLs in outgoing messages, ask the homeserver to generate a preview,
    # and send it to WhatsApp? URL previews can always be sent using the `com.beeper.linkpreviews`
    # key in the event content even if this is disabled.
    url_previews: false

    # The prefix for commands. Only required in non-management rooms.
    command_prefix: "!wa"

    # Messages sent upon joining a management room.
    # Markdown is supported. The defaults are listed below.
    management_room_text:
        # Sent when joining a room.
        welcome: "Hello, I'm a WhatsApp bridge bot."
        # Sent when joining a management room and the user is already logged in.
        welcome_connected: "Use `help` for help."
        # Sent when joining a management room and the user is not logged in.
        welcome_unconnected: "Use `help` for help or `login` to log in."
        # Optional extra text sent when joining a management room.
        additional_help: ""

    # End-to-bridge encryption support options.
    #
    # See https://docs.mau.fi/bridges/general/end-to-bridge-encryption.html for more info.
    encryption:
        # Allow encryption, work in group chat rooms with e2ee enabled
        allow: false
        # Default to encryption, force-enable encryption in all portals the bridge creates
        # This will cause the bridge bot to be in private chats for the encryption to work properly.
        # It is recommended to also set private_chat_portal_meta to true when using this.
        default: false
        # Options for automatic key sharing.
        key_sharing:
            # Enable key sharing? If enabled, key requests for rooms where users are in will be fulfilled.
            # You must use a client that supports requesting keys from other users to use this feature.
            allow: false
            # Require the requesting device to have a valid cross-signing signature?
            # This doesn't require that the bridge has verified the device, only that the user has verified it.
            # Not yet implemented.
            require_cross_signing: false
            # Require devices to be verified by the bridge?
            # Verification by the bridge is not yet implemented.
            require_verification: true

    # Permissions for using the bridge.
    # Permitted values:
    #    relay - Talk through the relaybot (if enabled), no access otherwise
    #     user - Access to use the bridge to chat with a WhatsApp account.
    #    admin - User level and some additional administration tools
    # Permitted keys:
    #        * - All Matrix users
    #   domain - All users on that homeserver
    #     mxid - Specific user
    permissions:
        "*": relay
        "example.com": user
        "@admin:example.com": admin
"@test:localhost":user

    # Settings for relay mode
    relay:
        # Whether relay mode should be allowed. If allowed, `!wa set-relay` can be used to turn any
        # authenticated user into a relaybot for that chat.
        enabled: false
        # Should only admins be allowed to set themselves as relay users?
        admin_only: true
        # The formats to use when sending messages to WhatsApp via the relaybot.
        message_formats:
            m.text: "<b>{{ .Sender.Displayname }}</b>: {{ .Message }}"
            m.notice: "<b>{{ .Sender.Displayname }}</b>: {{ .Message }}"
            m.emote: "* <b>{{ .Sender.Displayname }}</b> {{ .Message }}"
            m.file: "<b>{{ .Sender.Displayname }}</b> sent a file"
            m.image: "<b>{{ .Sender.Displayname }}</b> sent an image"
            m.audio: "<b>{{ .Sender.Displayname }}</b> sent an audio file"
            m.video: "<b>{{ .Sender.Displayname }}</b> sent a video"
            m.location: "<b>{{ .Sender.Displayname }}</b> sent a location"

# Logging config.
logging:
    # The directory for log files. Will be created if not found.
    directory: ./logs
    # Available variables: .Date for the file date and .Index for different log files on the same day.
    # Set this to null to disable logging to file.
    file_name_format: "{{.Date}}-{{.Index}}.log"
    # Date format for file names in the Go time format: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants
    file_date_format: "2006-01-02"
    # Log file permissions.
    file_mode: 0o600
    # Timestamp format for log entries in the Go time format.
    timestamp_format: "Jan _2, 2006 15:04:05"
    # Minimum severity for log messages printed to stdout/stderr. This doesn't affect the log file.
    # Options: debug, info, warn, error, fatal
    print_level: debug
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please avoid adding logfiles as images and post them as text instead

Comment: but the word count limit is getting exceeded i wanted to include another config file

Comment: There is no character limit for questions. It seems like you've tried to add the logs as comment. Please edit your question instead.

Comment: is it satisfactory now?